# Minikube does not honour Persistent Volumes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, minikube

I am trying to set up MariaDB with some persistent NFS volume using minikube. Every time I load the claim configuration, minikube creates a default persistent volumes instead of using the one I provide via NFS. I cannot work out why it does that…

The `mariadb-nfs-volume.yaml` file reads:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.3.121
    path: "/var/nfsshare"
    readOnly: false
```

And the `mariadb-pv-claim.yaml` file reads:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mariadb-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

And some debug:

```
; kubectl get pv nfs
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
nfs       10Gi       RWX           Retain          Available                                      56m
; kubectl get pvc mariadb-pv-claim
NAME               STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mariadb-pv-claim   Bound     pvc-7f20f205-49f2-11e7-83ab-525400dd1f77   3Gi        RWX           standard       56m
```

Comment: I recommend opening an issue on Minikube github repo.

Answer (score 3):

maybe a little late, but at least for the records here's an answer:

When creating the `PersistentVolume` give it a `storageClassName` (I use *mariadab-nfs* here):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: mariadb-nfs
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.3.121
    path: "/var/nfsshare"
    readOnly: false
```

and when claiming that volume, specify that very same storageClassName:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mariadb-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: mariadb-nfs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Kubernetes then will use the defined pv for the pvc, no need to disable the minikube dynamic provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

minikube has dynamic storage provisioning turned on by default. You can try to disable it so that your claim is met by your NFS PV.

```
minikube start --feature-gates=DynamicVolumeProvisioning=false
```